How to remove the text-decoration underline; from the span element inside the flex parent?
I want to remove the underline from the <span> tag inside the <p> tag, which has the display: flex; property.
The <p> tag in my case has to be flex.
I already searched this problem on the internet and found solutions that do not apply to a flex parent.
They said that adding text-decoration: none; and display: inline-block; to the span should fix the problem, but it does not.
<p style="display: flex; gap: 10px; text-decoration: underline;">
    This should have underline
    <span style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">This should not have underline</span>
</p>


Thanks for your responses. I restructured my html based on Temani Afif's answer. I realized that using flex on  was a bad idea and was just a result of rushing. If you want to use flex, always use it on containers like div.

You should never make a text container a flexbox container but if you want to keep the same configuration then use float on the span. It won't affect the layout, it will simply disable the underline propagation.


<p style="display: flex; gap: 10px; text-decoration: underline;">
    This should have underline
    <span style="float: left;">This should not have underline</span>
</p>




The snippet works fine for me on Windows 10 (Chrome/Edge) but not on IOS 16.... Safari.

If it is important not to change the HTML stucture, a slightly hacky way of achieving the correct visual effect is to give the span an explicit underline with color the same as background, in this case white.


<p style="display: flex; gap: 10px; text-decoration: underline;">
  This should have underline
  <span style="text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color: white;">This should not have underline</span>
</p>




Remove display:flex; on <p> should work.


<p style="text-decoration: underline;">
  This should have underline
  <span style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">This should not have underline</span>
</p>




It was a specific requirement that the p element be flex.
